# The following code works in my IDE but fails to work in the online editor provided at hackerrank.com

Tags: java, printf

> Input Format
>
> Every line of input will contain a String followed by an integer. Each String will have a maximum of 10 alphabetic characters, and each
>   integer will be in the inclusive range from 0 to 999.
>
> Output Format
>
> In each line of output there should be two columns: The first column contains the String and is left justified using exactly 15 characters.
>   The second column contains the integer, expressed in exactly 3 digits;
>   if the original input has less than three digits, you must pad your
>   output's leading digits with zeroes.
>
> Sample Input
>
> ```
> java 100
> cpp 65
> python 50
> ```
>
> Sample Output
>
> ```
> ================================
> java           100 
> cpp            065 
> python         050 
> ================================
> ```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            int x=0,len=0;

            System.out.println("================================");
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                boolean bool = true;

                while(bool){
                    sb=sb.append(sc.next());
                    len=sb.toString().length();
                    if(len>10) {
                        sb.delete(0,len);
                        System.out.println("Enter zero - ten character string");

                    }
                    else
                        bool = false;
                }

                bool= true;


                while(bool){
                    x=Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
                    sc.nextLine();
                    int l= Integer.toString(x).length();
                    if(l>3) {
                        System.out.println("Enter zero - three digit number");

                    }
                    else
                        bool = false;

                }


                System.out.printf("%1$-16s %2$03d\n",sb,x);
                sb=sb.delete(0,len);
            }

            System.out.println("================================");

        }
    }
```

Comment: You should tell us how it "fails".

Comment: a link to the editor would be useful

Comment: My output and expected output look the same but the compiler throws a message "Wrong Answer"

Comment: [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-output-formatting/copy-from/18264701)

Comment: This is my second time today to see question about hackerrank with too many quote markup `>`...

Comment: Apologies i just started using stack overflow..wasnt really familiar with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You printed two extra space characters between each strings and numbers.

Try Replacing

```
System.out.printf("%1$-16s %2$03d\n",sb,x);
```

with

```
System.out.printf("%1$-15s%2$03d \n",sb,x);
```

Also you should remove the line `sc.nextLine();` to avoid extra reading and causing an exceition.

Comment: This approach would also answer your question.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("================================");
        for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
            String s1 = sc.next();
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.format("%-15s%03d%n", s1, x);
        }
        System.out.println("================================");
}
}